# C Error: `arithmetic on pointer to an incomplete type`

Tags: c, eclipse, pointers, struct, typedef

If I have the definitions:

```
typedef struct y_t *Y;
```

and

```
typedef struct x_t *X;    
struct x_t {
    Y *b;
    Y a;
    int size;
};
```

(`b` is an array of type `Y` of size `size`)

and I have

```
int func(X x) {    
    int diff = x->a - x->b[0];   // error here
    return diff;
}
```

Let's assume `a` is an element in the `b` array, and `func` needs to return `a`'s index in `b` array.

But I'm getting an error `arithmetic on pointer to an incomplete type` (I'm using eclipse).

I'm assuming it has trouble because it doesn't know the dimension of the array... So how can I fix `func`?

Comment: "b is an array of type Y of size size" -- no `b` is a *pointer* to a `Y`, which apparently is supposed to be the first `Y` in an array of length `size`.  Pointers are not the same thing as arrays.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks. so I can't fix `func`? maybe with `size` some way?

Comment: See my just-posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message ...

> arithmetic on pointer to an incomplete type

... likely arises because the declaration of `struct y_t` is not visible at that point in the compilation unit.  The typedef of `Y` serves double-duty as a forward declaration of such a structure, but without a full declaration, `struct y_t` is an incomplete type.

Both `x->a` and `x->b[0]` are `Y`s, a.k.a. `struct y_t *`.  The difference between them is defined in terms of the size of the pointed-to structure, but its size is unknown because it is an incomplete type.  You need to provide the declaration of `struct y_t` for what you're doing to work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because you are trying to index a variable that is not an array. When you de-reference an array, as you've done here:

```
Y *b
```

You are already accessing the 0th index of the array in your struct definition. So just change your line to this:

```
int diff = x->a - x->b;
```

Comment: Now `invalid operands to binary - (have ‘Y’ and ‘struct y_t **’)`